# Sprite text at incorrect position

Tags: android, actionscript-3, haxe, openfl

I'd like to add text to a working button. Currently, the code below prints the text at 0,0 rather than on the sprite button.

```
    soundButton.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
    soundButton.graphics.drawRect(0,900, 200, 50);
    soundButton.graphics.endFill();
    this.addChild(soundButton);

    var soundtext:TextField = new TextField();
    soundtext.text ="Sound On"; // default value
    soundButton.addChild(soundtext);
    soundButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK,sound_CLICK);
```

Additionally, I'd like to add code to the listener below to have the button text reflect the state of the boolean doSound.

```
    private function sound_CLICK (event:MouseEvent):Void {  
           doSound = !doSound; 
           // swap sprite button text Sound on/Sound off

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the x and y property's of the Text Field to position the text on the button?

If there's something I'm missing ill update my answer.

Comment: Duh. For some reason I thought the x,y was inherited from the sprite. Thank you very much!